# reuse key in the same object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to avoid to repeat each time

`$('.element1')`,
`$('.element1').html()`,

in

```
myList = [
    {
        element: $('.element1'),
        text: element.html(),
        value: 'somevalue'
    },
    {
        element: $('.element2'),
        text: element.html(),
        value: 'somevalue'
    }
];
```

but actually it is not working, it shows me the eroor:
***Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined***

I need to define and keep everything only inside the "myList",
avoiding to define other external variables etc, and I would like to know how I can use something like `this`

I really appreciate any help

Comment: jquery returns an object so you may have to use element : { $('.element1') }, (only guessing at this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable before.
Property/key of objects are not variable themselves in the current scope.

```
var element = $('.element1');
var element2 = $('.element2');

myList = [
    {
        element: element,
        text: element.html(),
        value: 'somevalue'
    },
    {
        element: element2,
        text: element2.html(),
        value: 'somevalue'
    }
];
```

Also check here for possible one time initialization of the object.
This would not save you so much typing and code.

[Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

is not really clear why you want to avoid to repeat them and keep all of them in the object, of course saving the processing of jquery functions is a reason.

Comment: I need to define and keep everything only inside the "myList",
avoiding to define other external variables etc, and I would like to know how I can use something

Comment: Also, it is a good practice to use a `$` prefix for variables which are jQuery objects. So, it is better to name them `$element` and `$element2`.

Comment: I prefer to do not mess up with the dollar that for me is a php variable long before than a javascript jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

You want to separate your data from your logic a bit more, so that it can scale later

```
myList = [
    {
        element: '.element1',
        value: 'somevalue'
    },
    {
        element: '.element2',
        value: 'somevalue'
    }
];

myList.forEach(function(elem) {
   $(elem.element).html(elem.value)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    myList = [
        {
            element: $('.element1'),
            value: 'somevalue'
        },
        {
            element: $('.element2'),
            value: 'somevalue'
        }

    ];
    for( var i in myList ) {
        myList[ i ]["text"] = myList[ i ][ "element" ].html();
    }
```